# Java Programming - Beginner

Tags: java

I need some assistance correctly setting up my Terminal on Mac to run Java programs, and I also need some assistance with my first java programming homework assignment. I don't want anybody to do it for me just guidance would be more than appreciated! Thank you!

Practice HelloWorld program is at : http://cnx.org/contents/d31a3ff4-95f3-45b5-a56e-b83823a45650@10/Java3000:_The_Guzdial-Ericson_

I have dr.java for writing the programs, is this a good text editor?

Comment: download eclipse IDE, it will speed up your development process.

Comment: Some people would disagree with TheLostMind and recommend Netbeans ;)

Comment: @Fildor - Some people might disagree with both TheLostMind and Fildor and recommend *NotePad* :P

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming!  There is nothing to "setup" on your terminal.  You need to understand directory structure and how to compile and run the code using the terminal.

Comment: @TheLostMind has a good point here. A plain text editor is good for learning all the nifty things of typing in javac commands and fiddling with build-scripts ... All the IDE's do that for you and thus hiding most of it from users.

Comment: thank yall for your answers! I really appreciate it!! does eclipse (or netbeans) work well on windows; for example: if I save a java program in eclipse/netbeans on my mac and send it to my professor can he open it on windows and it still run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with Eclipse when I program in Java. If you want to remember the code it is better if you use Notepad++ where you have to write everything without autocompletion.

To run java programs in terminal on MAC :

- Open the terminal
- Change the directory to the folder where your java files are

  `$ cd`
- Compile the java file using the command with the appropriate name of the file

  `$ javac Name.java`
- Run it by using

  `$ java Name`

Comment: *Change the directory to the folder where your java files are* - Alternatively, you could *provide* the complete / absolute path to the file. Also you have to make sure that you have set `Path` variable correctly.

Comment: As an addition: On Mac there is no need to set the Path variable since Java comes pre-installed. Also the OP can type cd and then drag the java file into the terminal rather than typing the path by himself

Comment: thank yall for your answers! I really appreciate it!! does eclipse (or netbeans) work well on windows; for example: if I save a java program in eclipse/netbeans on my mac and send it to my professor can he open it on windows and it still run correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Java desktop applications should be developed in [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), here you have a graphical GUI designer and you are rid of command line programs like `javac` and `java`.

Answer (score 0):

There are Five ways for Learning Java Programming
It’s a great skill to learn Java programming is almost the most widely known coding language we have, so, if we would like to start java programming.

1). Java Programming Basics
This is something you can start right away studying the basics online is a our Java programming starts out at the same point. Learn the basics about Java programming is the right way to initiate.

2). Practice Coding at any platform or itself on complier
The best thing to do is get started once you’ve come to grips with the basics. As we know that practice makes a man perfect.

3). Map Your Codes on copy with dry and run process.
it  is a nice way to practice for java programming  for beginners. Try and check(Dry run).

4).Study about basics on Java Programming Regularly either on net or any platform.
Java programming, As we all know that most of your content can be found online on net as well as on YouTube. we will updated, regularly checked sources well websites.

5). Algo Check every time with optimization
To make perfect our algorithm, you’ll need to be able to understand the basics of Java. You’ll create and solve a problem for itself in our days basis of code solving practicing in Java programming.